# C++ How to I read column from text file?

Tags: c++, file, sorting, text

I have a project in c++, and need to find largest filename from the text file.
My text file example is:

```
foundedindex = instline.find("  ");
    inst_host = instline.substr(0, foundedindex);
    //cout << inst_host << " a" << endl;
    obj[count].sethost(inst_title);
```

So, I want to read only "index.html", "23,html", "24.html" etc.
When I seperate all line by one by like in code, sorting takes too much time.
Please help me.

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect.

Comment: Use `std::getline()`, `std::istringstream` and the extraction operator `>>` to get only a part of a line of input.

Comment: You seem to have code and data mixed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way to get the columns of each line.

```
std::string temp;
std::vector<vector<std::string>> data;
while(std::getline(file, temp))
{
    std::vector<std::string> x;
    std::istringstream liney(temp);
    while(std::getline(liney, temp, ' '))
    {
        x.push_back(temp);
    }
    data.push_back(x);
}
// Then using a column loop through a 2d array.
int row = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<data[row].size(); i++)
{
    for(int s = 0; s<data.size(); s++)
    {
       data[s][i]; // Do something
    }
    row++;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @user0042 I edited my post to reflect your suggestion

Comment: @user0042 sorry about that, this should be good.

Comment: @Alkyonemis If this works please upvote and accept.